# why width property doesn't change from code - WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a grid in WPF application which contains 2 grids.
The inner grids are width binding - one depend on the other.
I change the width of one grid from code with a story board and it works.
but when I try to change it in another method, it does nothing.
what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the storyboard isn't constantly putting it's final value in to the width property on your grid, you can turn this off by giving it a FillBehavior of Stop. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx)

```
<Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
```